# Julia 1.5.2 Initiating random number selection in parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, julia, random-seed

I am currently attempting to run my code in parallel. Part of my code (genetic algorithm) relies on the selection of random numbers. Therefore, I need to make sure that each thread used, have their own random number generator. I must also be able to replicate the results. Therefore, I have "borrowed" a function, which has the ability to set a random seed or create specific seeds for each thread.

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-do-i-deal-with-random-number-generation-when-multithreading/5636/2

In order to test if this was working correctly, I wanted to set the seeds equal for each thread and test to see if the same random numbers were generated. However, this was not the case!

I believe that I am missing something fundamental about the generation of the numbers. When creating the random number generators, I have used the same `UInt32`. I believe that they should therefore draw the same numbers, however the `randjump` may interfere with this. Perhaps the random number generators do not "jump" forward to the same point/state to ensure that each is far enough from each other in the cycle. Perhaps they share a state when doing it this way? Is there a way to control if the implementation is accurate? Perhaps there is a bigger error at play here?

```
clearconsole()
using Test
using Random
using Future
using Test

function set_rngs(random_seed)
    if random_seed == true
        rng_seed = Random.make_seed()
        rng = MersenneTwister(rng_seed)
        return Future.randjump(rng, Threads.nthreads());
    else
        rng_seed = UInt32[0xbd8e7dc4,0xbd8e7dc4];
        rng = Random.MersenneTwister(rng_seed)
        return Future.randjump(rng, Threads.nthreads());
    end
end

function random_test()
    tmp = Vector{Float64}(undef, 100)

    Threads.@threads for i in 1:100
        tmp[i] = rand()
    end
    return tmp
end

Random.seed!(set_rngs(false))
tester = random_test()


function testing_rand(tester::Vector{Float64})
    @testset "Testing if random numbers drawn by each processer are different" begin
        for i in 1:50
            @test tester[i] != tester[i+50]
        end
    end
end

testing_rand(tester)
```

Comment: I'm quite confused what the code is supposed to do? What would you expect the result to be? There are two totally unrelated parts in your snippets: 1) the call to `Random.seed!(...)` which initializes a `MersenneTwister` object, and 2) `random_test`, which calls `rand()` in a threaded loop, which doesn't use the RNG from 1)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically do not need to use `randjump` because the `MersenneTwister` streams are not correlated.

Hence, the standard way to initiate the random streams for threads is the following:

```
using Random
const mts = MersenneTwister.(1:Threads.nthreads())
```

When writing a code you always access an approppiate random state via:

```
rand(mts[Threads.threadid()])
```

On some rare occasion you might indeed want to have different parts of the same random stream and need to perform `randjump`.

```
const mts2 = [Future.randjump(MersenneTwister(0), i) for i in 1:Threads.nthreads()]
```

The access pattern to the object is the same as above. Note that in each case you need to hold a separate random state for each thread. This approach is also recommended for performance reasons (rather than several threads competing for a single random state).

Comment: We meet again! Thank you very much! This was much simpler to implement and to get to work. The test fails when it should and passes when it should. To replicate the results i currently define the mts for each thread and use a loop to set the seed for each thread. Thanks again!